# Pandas create a custom groupby aggregation for column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to create a new column that is a function of two column's aggregation, so that for any arbitrary grouping it preserves the function? This would be functionally similar to creating a calculated column in excel and pivoting by labels.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['lab1','lab2']*5,'A':[1,2]*5,'B':[4,5]*5})
df1['C'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['A']/x['B'],axis=1)
pd.pivot_table(df1,index='lab',{'A':sum,'B':sum,'C':lambda x: x['A']/x['B']})
```

should return:

`|lab|A B|C|
|----|---|---|
|lab1|5 |20|.25|
|lab2|10|25 |.4|`

i'd like to aggregate by 'lab' (or any combination of labels) and have the dataframe return the aggregation without having to re-define the column calculation. I realize this is trivial to manually code, but it's repetitive when you have many columns.

Comment: Would you mind posting your expected result? It isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can do this using `apply` or `agg`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Method 1
df1.groupby('lab').apply(lambda df: pd.Series({'A': df['A'].sum(), 'B': df['B'].sum(), 'C': df['C'].unique()[0]})).reset_index()

# Method 2
df1.groupby('lab').agg({'A': 'sum',
                    'B': 'sum',
                    'C': lambda x: np.unique(x)}).reset_index()

# output
     lab  A    B   C
0   lab1  5    20 0.25
1   lab2  10   25 0.40
```

Comment: thanks! could you please show how to use agg() that references specific columns? I don't think this solution will work for other examples, such as

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lab':['lab1','lab2']*5,'A':np.random.randint(1,11,10),'B':np.random.randint(1,11,10)})

Comment: In `agg`, we pass a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary is the name of the column from df and value is the function. A function can be passed as a string or in custom lambda form. It should work on your new example too.

Comment: got it. this produces the output i want:
df1.groupby('lab').apply(lambda df: pd.Series({'A': df['A'].sum(), 'B': df['B'].sum(), 'C': df['A'].sum()/df['B'].sum()})).reset_index()

however, im pretty unclear what Pandas is actually doing here.

Comment: @Jonathan umm... are you after: `df1.groupby('lab', as_index=False).sum().assign(C=lambda L: L.A / L.B)` ?

Comment: yes, partially. like i said in my description i know this is possible to do like this. I am looking for a practical way to encapsulate the aggregation logic in the column itself. I don't want to have to re-assign variables after each transformation. Ideally, the dataframe would reference that lambda function defined elsewhere, and use the generic .agg() in one go without using apply